# How to indent section contents with section title string

Tags: indentation

Consider this example

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{My Section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

This generates doc like (pardon my paint skills)

[image]

I want my texts (all paragraphs) to be indented on section header text not the section number text. How to obtain this?

Note that in my original issue I have no access to document contents, only to the preamble of the latex file (this is part of mapping a doc template to latex template). So a solution with only preamble change is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet your requirement

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{My Section}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,labelsep=3.5em,label=]
\item \lipsum[1-2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works but not in my actual problem. In my actual problem I don't have access to content of the text. The solution need to be done by modifying preamble only! Any ideas with that?

Comment: @MaloyGhosh please note that your requirement has changed -- it would be only courteous to accept the answer provided to your original post - your new requirement can be given as a new question -- there are a number of experts to help on the site

Answer (score 1):

Problem with indenting is that the section title position is not fixed but depends on how many digits the section and chapter numbers have.

Another approach: place the section numbers in the margin

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\newcommand*{\numberinmargin}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\numberinmargin{\thechapter}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\numberinmargin{\thesection}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{My Section}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding your alternate suggestion, I was thinking of shifting the text margin to right and then use titlesec package to drag the section header to left. But I couldn't do the margin shifting part. Any ideas?